# Alternative way of implementing a groupBy method in Scala?

Tags: scala, language-features

I've come up with this implementation of `groupBy`:

```
object Whatever
{
    def groupBy[T](in:Seq[T],p:T=>Boolean) : Map[Boolean,List[T]] = {
        var result = Map[Boolean,List[T]]()
        in.foreach(i => {
            val res = p(i)
            var existing = List[T]() // how else could I declare the reference here? If I write var existing = null I get a compile-time error.
            if(result.contains(res))
                existing = result(res)
            else {
                existing = List[T]()
            }
            existing ::= i
            result += res -> existing
        })
        return result   
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem very Scalish ( is that the word I'm looking for? ) to me. Could you maybe suggest some improvements?

EDIT: after I received the "hint" about folding, I've implemented it this way:

```
def groupFold[T](in:Seq[T],p:T=>Boolean):Map[Boolean,List[T]] = {
        in.foldLeft(Map[Boolean,List[T]]()) ( (m,e) => {
           val res = p(e)
           m(res) = e :: m.getOrElse(res,Nil)
        })
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: The fold implementation is especially useful when you have more values than Boolean has.  Note that you could replace Boolean with a generic type U and the fold would still work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to group by a predicate (ie, a function of `T => Boolean`), then you probably just want to do this:

```
in partition p
```

If you truly want to create a map out of it, then:

```
val (t, f) = in partition p
Map(true -> t, false -> f)
```

Then again, you may just want the exercise. In that case, the fold solution is fine.

Comment: @Geo You may also want to look at `splitAt` and `span`, which do something similar but with different criteria. The first divides between `take` and `drop`, while the second divides between `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example using `foldLeft`.

```
scala> def group[T, U](in: Iterable[T], f: T => U) = {
     |   in.foldLeft(Map.empty[U, List[T]]) {
     |     (map, t) =>
     |       val groupByVal = f(t)
     |       map.updated(groupByVal, t :: map.getOrElse(groupByVal, List.empty))
     |   }.mapValues(_.reverse)
     | }
group: [T,U](in: Iterable[T],f: (T) => U)java.lang.Object with scala.collection.DefaultMap[U,List[T]]

scala> val ls = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ls: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> println(group(ls, (_: Int) % 2))
Map(1 -> List(1, 3, 5), 0 -> List(2, 4))
```

Scala 2.8 offers this in the standard library:

```
scala> println(ls.groupBy((_: Int) % 2)) // Built into Scala 2.8.
Map(1 -> List(1, 3, 5), 0 -> List(2, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just filter twice.

```
object Whatever {
  def groupBy[T](in: Seq[T], p: T => Boolean) : Map[Boolean,List[T]] = {
    Map( false -> in.filter(!p(_)).toList , true -> in.filter(p(_)).toList )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little hint: Use [*folds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) to compute the resulting list in a functional/immutable fashion.